# How do I use ̭̘͕̼̱̭̀Z̛̦A̼͘ͅL͚G͔͇̟͓̀O!̴͕̤̺̠ text in python?

Tags: python, text, zalgo

So I'm trying to use Zalgo Text in Python to add an element of spookiness to my text-based console game. However, everytime I do try to add it, I would get errors. Now when I try to recreate said errors, nothing happens and my console just doesn't update. Does anyone know why this would happen, and how i can print Zalgo text? I tried pyzalgo but the documentation doesn't realy show you how to use it. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import os
import time
import pyzalgo

os.system("mode con: cols=45 lines=80")

def main():
    print("***************************************")
    print("T̶̝̮̯̩̤̮̟̯̟͍͈͔̣̣̫̋̏͌̌̆́̌ḧ̷̝̼̲̿͗̓̈̚͘ę̴̢̢̱͉̫̙̗̙͎̘̺͇̤̺̔̇̋͗̈́̌͋̿̈́͝ ̴̢̛̳̗͍̝̲̗͓̤̬͐̍̽̋̅̿̀w̷͍̜̪̫̦͚͚̬̜̹̭͖͌ͅr̶͔̱͓̦̝͕̘̼͙̫̘͇̓͐͌͛̉̈́̏̈͂̍ą̵̞̣̣͓̳̲̮͉̭̗͎̱̮̹̄̀̀́͗͒̄̽͠t̷̡̛̞̯̘̟͉̻̜̖́̀̃̅͆͐̎̎̄͘h̴̨̫̱̺̫͕̹̳̲̊̆̋̌͛͗͜͝ͅ ̶̟͚̖̥͔̟̖̭̦͕̘̗̤̀̄͌̈́̓̕͘ͅo̶̙̟̼̓f̷̛̣̏́͌͌̏̊͗̀̇͠͠͝ ̷̛̪͕̖̙̗͉͍̪̪̳͊̃̈̕͝Z̷̟̳͉̱͓̫̦̱̥̃̃́́̆̑͠ą̸̮̲͍̯͉͉̍͜͜ͅl̶̡̯̞̝̥̖̤͈̬̫̭͚̝͇͖̉̅́͌̋̍͘̚͝g̸͎͍̺̣̱̬̞̣͌͝o̵̩̖̥̅͂̔̈́͆̑͋͌͐͝")
    print("1. Start")
    print("2. Load")
    print("3. Exit")
    print("***************************************")

main()
```

Comment: Apparently, you are trying this on Windows. Zalgo requires Unicode support to work, but Windows console isn't supporting Unicode out of the box, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console. Second, I don't think calling `mode con:` will work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks! and Yeah, the calling mode con: hasn't been working. I'm using WING IDE to work on my AP Comp Sci project, and right now i want to set the demensions of the console window. I also don't know how to open the default console instead of the IDE;s. Would you know how to do that?